# How to Enable Auto-Sync in android using tasker's run shell action?

Tags: android, shell, adb, tasker

On my Gionee M3(MTK-6582) Auto-sync disables it self automatically. so i am trying to find a way to turn it on using tasker's run shell action.

I've already tried putting "ContentResolver.setMasterSyncAutomatically(true)" without quotation marks, in Tasker's Run Shell action. I did not work.

If there is a way to do it, then please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- create new task
- add an action
- select network
- select AutoSync
- set option to "on"

Comment: Oh right, I completely forgot about that action. I've got what i was looking for, thank you.

Comment: It would be nice if you could mark the answer as a solution to the problem - thx!

Comment: Sure, it's my first time asking on stack overflow.